# Can We Set Session Time-Out for a Specific Sessoin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, devise, two-factor-authentication

I am currently working on Two-Factor Authentication on Devise and Wanted to Store User ID in Temporary Session for 2 Min can I Set the Timeout for this Session Only.

```
session[:user_id] = "USER_ID_HERE"
```

I want something like this:-

```
session[:user_id].timeout = 2.minutes
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

For this session only you can store current time in session as well:

```
session[:user_id] = "USER_ID_HERE"
session[:expires_at] = Time.current + 2.minutes
```

Then, in `before_action` define some method to check:

```
if session[:expires_at] < Time.current
  session.delete(:user_id)
  session.delete(:expires_at)
end
```